Oracle database seems to be locked
I have executed the query below in SQL Developer to update a column in a table for all the rows:
update table set column xx = NULL
For some reason after doing it I cant change any value in the database. The same behavior has happened in two different environments.
Is there anything wrong with my query? I have run commit; and rollback; to try to solve the issue with no success. At the moment even if I try to change one simple value in a row it times out.
Perhaps the problem has been caused by a different circumstance but the issue started happening after I run my query.
Thank you in advance!

For some reason after doing it I cant change any value in the database - In the database or just the table which you updated ?

how many rows in that table ? When you ran that update statement, did you see the message "n rows updated" in the script output pane ? Depending on lots of thing, that update statement could take some time are you sure it finished ? If you update all rows in the table then oracle will lock all rows during the update - see this post

You'll need to engage your DBA. Folks here cannot see into your database to diagnose system health issues.

If this really affects the entire database, and not just the same table in different sessions, perhaps a tablespace is full and all of your sessions are waiting for more space. Check select * from dba_resumable;

Thanks all for your suggestions. In the end there was another process using the database heavily which was causing the problem.

Is it any table which you can't interact with or just that particular one?
If it's a large table and you left the update running for a long time and then killed your session, there may be a delay before the Oracle smon process kicks in and gets the changes rolled back. In the meantime there may be losts of locked rows. Any attempted updates to such rows, will appear to hang (they are just queuing, waiting for locks to be released).
